# How to render object data based on if else condition using data payload?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Based on the quantity of given array of objects structure, how can I set if else conditional to display the specific budget payload? For example, if quantity is equal to 10 then I need to output to the user the budget data that belongs in the first object in json payload structure, and if the quantity is equal to 50 then I need to display the second object data in json payload structure.

```
data = [
  {
    quantity: 10,
    budget: {
      share: {
        "fedRate": [
          85214,
          98542,
          32874
        ],
        "appShare": [
          99965,
          11012,
          87785
        ]
      } 
    }  
  },
  {
    quantity: 50,
    budget: {
      share: {
        "fedRate": [
          33354,
          69856,
          32563
        ],
        "appShare": [
          55555,
          74312,
          15897
        ]
      } 
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first iterate through the array and then check for each index like this:

```
for( i=0 ;i<data.length; i++){
if(data[i].quantity == 10){
 console.log(data[i].budget);
}
else if(data[i].quantity == 50){
 console.log(data[i].budget)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: my pleasure @user10248088

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    quantity: 10,
    budget: {
      share: {
        "fedRate": [
          85214,
          98542,
          32874
        ],
        "appShare": [
          99965,
          11012,
          87785
        ]
      } 
    }  
  },
  {
    quantity: 50,
    budget: {
      share: {
        "fedRate": [
          33354,
          69856,
          32563
        ],
        "appShare": [
          55555,
          74312,
          15897
        ]
      } 
    }
  }
]

// I would use the Array filter method
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
const output = data.filter(obj => obj.quantity === 10);
console.log(output[0].budget);

// You could also create a function if you need to reuse this logic
function getBudgetData(quantity, data) {
  const items = data.filter(obj => obj.quantity === quantity);
  return items[0].budget;
}

console.log(getBudgetData(10, data))
```